# How to split string into column

Tags: python, csv

I got a `csv` file with some  data, and  I want to split this data.

My column one contains a  title, my column 2 contains some dates, and my  column 3 contains some text linked to the dates.

I want to transform  that in something like :

```
title 0 Date 0.1 text 0.1
title 0 Date 0.2 text 0.2
title 1 date 1.0 text 1.0
title 1 date 1.1 text 1.1
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you show that what you have tried so far and where you encountered with a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you have a csv file which looks like this:

```
title1,date1,text1
title2,date2,text2
title3,date3,text3
```

If you want to split the rows, simply use the `.split()`-function.

In this case, it'd look similar to this:

```
columns = row.split(',')
```

The `.split()`-function returns an array full of strings, therefore, if you want to access column 1, you have to say `columns[0]`.

If it's the first row, `columns[0]` would give you `title1` with my data above.

---

Another example:

```
filename = 'data.txt'
lines = [line.strip() for line in open(filename)]
for row in lines:
    columns = row.split(',')
    print ' '.join(columns)
```

Using this code, gives you the following output:

```
title1 date1 text1
title2 date2 text2
title3 date3 text3
```

Comment: i use Split fonction Works perfect Thank You